# FLASK PYTHON ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, numpy, flutter, tensorflow, flask

I want a convolutional neural network in my flutter app so i want to use flask. I integrate flask with python with a simple function and it works

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    return 'Hi how are you'
```

Then i create the endpoint to create a CNN but the imports starts to fail,
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy '
...
It seems like i don't have python no ?? I don't know the solution,  here is the code. Thank you

```
from flask import Flask;
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.layers  as KL
import tensorflow.keras.models  as KM
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    import numpy as np # linear algebra
    import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
    
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    @app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
    def index():
        return 'Hi how are you'
    
    
    @app.route('/train', methods = ['GET'])
    def index():
        mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
        (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
        x_train, x_test = x_train/255.0, x_test/255.0
        x_train, x_test = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1), np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=-1)
        model = models.Sequential()
    
        model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
        model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
        model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
        model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
        model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
        model.add(layers.Flatten())
        model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
        model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    
        model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
        history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5,
                        validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
    
        return model
```

Comment: Have you made sure you installed it?

Comment: yes i installed i did a simple example

Answer (score 2):

No! Don't do that!
*Usually* you will:

- develop and train your model offline (unless you're retraining continuously, which is another case)
- Save the model to a file (think about an artifact)
- Then develop a backend as thin as possible (Flask is a good choice) to do inference (running the model) and give data to users (the ones using your flutter app).

How to do it:

- Install tensorflow (with keras support).
- Move the code you have on the /train method to a `train.py` file.
- Add `model.save('model_name.h5')` at the end of the `train.py`file.

Now change the flask backend:

- You need to load the model file when your backend starts.`model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model_name.h5')`
- Add a flask method to do the inference (/predict). In short: grab the input you receive, sanitize it a bit (reject nulls, and strange stuff), make a prediction with `model_output = model.predict(input_data)', and finally adapt the model output to something you can handle in flutter.

Comment: Heii thank you for the answer but if I want to create a CNN with images that the user will upload ?? its like you say (unless you're retraining continuously, which is another case) What is this case ??

Comment: @PaulBombay you _usually_ use continuous retraining in security where the situation changes very quickly (a backgound process grabs samples and trains a model that detects anomalies, then checks its performance and deploys it if it is good enough).

Comment: What i want is create a CNN with photos that the user has done, so i can train the model fiirst and then export the model  ( develop and train your model offline ) this i can't do it, So what is the soluton ??

Answer (score 0):

What version of Python are you using? If you are using Python 2.7, then Tensroflow might not work.

Comment: I use python 3.9